# Working with big data on Dask Kubernetes in Azure Kubernetes Service(AKS)

Tags: kubernetes, dataset, dask, azure-aks, dask-kubernetes

*I want do analysis on a dataset(like csv file) of 8gb which is in my laptop hard disk. I have already setup a dask kubernetes cluster on AKS with 1 scheduler and 3 worker with 7 gb each.*

**How can I work on my dataset using this dask kubernetes cluster on AKS?
Which file system to share dataset between worker will be best for this purpose?**

Any suggestion where I should store this dataset so that I can work on this dataset easily.

The method should work from both a jupyter notebook and from a python file also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably want to upload your data to an Azure blob store.  There is more information about dask remote data (including Azure) here:

https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/remote-data-services.html